# Duplicates even there are no duplicates

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I have a data frame as a result of multiple joins. When I check, it tells me that I have a duplicate, even though that is impossible from my perspective. Here is an abstract example:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, IntegerType, StringType
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit

# Create a Spark session
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("CreateDataFrame").getOrCreate()

# User input for number of rows
n_a = 10
n_a_c = 5
n_a_c_d = 3
n_a_c_e = 4

# Define the schema for the DataFrame
schema_a = StructType([StructField("id1", StringType(), True)])
schema_a_b = StructType(
    [
        StructField("id1", StringType(), True),
        StructField("id2", StringType(), True),
        StructField("extra", StringType(), True),
    ]
)
schema_a_c = StructType(
    [
        StructField("id1", StringType(), True),
        StructField("id3", StringType(), True),
    ]
)
schema_a_c_d = StructType(
    [
        StructField("id3", StringType(), True),
        StructField("id4", StringType(), True),
    ]
)
schema_a_c_e = StructType(
    [
        StructField("id3", StringType(), True),
        StructField("id5", StringType(), True),
    ]
)

# Create a list of rows with increasing integer values for "id1" and a constant value of "1" for "id2"
rows_a = [(str(i),) for i in range(1, n_a + 1)]
rows_a_integers = [str(i) for i in range(1, n_a + 1)]
rows_a_b = [(str(i), str(1), "A") for i in range(1, n_a + 1)]


def get_2d_list(ids_part_1: list, n_new_ids: int):
    rows = [
        [
            (str(i), str(i) + "_" + str(j))
            for i in ids_part_1
            for j in range(1, n_new_ids + 1)
        ]
    ]
    return [item for sublist in rows for item in sublist]


rows_a_c = get_2d_list(ids_part_1=rows_a_integers, n_new_ids=n_a_c)
rows_a_c_d = get_2d_list(ids_part_1=[i[1] for i in rows_a_c], n_new_ids=n_a_c_d)
rows_a_c_e = get_2d_list(ids_part_1=[i[1] for i in rows_a_c], n_new_ids=n_a_c_e)

# Create the DataFrame
df_a = spark.createDataFrame(rows_a, schema_a)
df_a_b = spark.createDataFrame(rows_a_b, schema_a_b)
df_a_c = spark.createDataFrame(rows_a_c, schema_a_c)
df_a_c_d = spark.createDataFrame(rows_a_c_d, schema_a_c_d)
df_a_c_e = spark.createDataFrame(rows_a_c_e, schema_a_c_e)

# Join everything
df_join = (
    df_a.join(df_a_b, on="id1")
    .join(df_a_c, on="id1")
    .join(df_a_c_d, on="id3")
    .join(df_a_c_e, on="id3")
)

# Nested structure
# show
df_nested = df_join.withColumn("id3", f.struct(f.col("id3"))).orderBy("id3")

for i, index in enumerate([(5, 3), (4, 3), (3, None)]):
    remaining_columns = list(set(df_nested.columns).difference(set([f"id{index[0]}"])))
    df_nested = (
        df_nested.groupby(*remaining_columns)
        .agg(f.collect_list(f.col(f"id{index[0]}")).alias(f"id{index[0]}_tmp"))
        .drop(f"id{index[0]}")
        .withColumnRenamed(
            f"id{index[0]}_tmp",
            f"id{index[0]}",
        )
    )

    if index[1]:
        df_nested = df_nested.withColumn(
            f"id{index[1]}",
            f.struct(
                f.col(f"id{index[1]}.*"),
                f.col(f"id{index[0]}"),
            ).alias(f"id{index[1]}"),
        ).drop(f"id{index[0]}")
```

I check for duplicates based on `id3` which should be unique the entire data frame on the second level:

```
# Investigate for duplicates
df_test = df_nested.select("id2", "extra", f.explode(f.col("id3")["id3"]).alias("id3"))
df_test.groupby("id3").count().filter(f.col("count") > 1).show()
```

Which tell me that `ID3 == 8_3` exists twice:

```
+---+-----+
|id3|count|
+---+-----+
|8_3|    2|
+---+-----+
```

However, in the data frame is clearly unique for ID3. Which can be shown by (ID4 and ID5 are on the next level)

```
df_join.groupby("id3", "id4", "id5").count().filter(f.col("count") > 1).show()
```

leading to

```
+---+---+---+-----+
|id3|id4|id5|count|
+---+---+---+-----+
+---+---+---+-----+
```

If it helps I use Databricks Runtime Version 11.3 LTS (includes Apache Spark 3.3.0, Scala
2.12)

Comment: What do you see if you just do `print(df_test[df_test['id3'] == "8_3"])`? That should show you the duplicate rows.

Comment: `df_test[df_test['id3'] == "8_3"]` shows me twice `|id2|extra|id3| := |  1|    A|8_3|`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are grouping the data frames and aggregating grouped elements into an array. All of this in a loop. Grouping is also performed on previously collected arrays.

The missed assumption is that when you `collect_list` of **same elements**, you're going to **get the same array**. But is does not hold as spark does not guarantee the order of elements in the result of `collect_list`.
[The docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#collect_listz) specifically say:

> The function is non-deterministic because the order of collected results depends on the order of the rows which may be non-deterministic after a shuffle.

For some reason the values of `8_3` are collected out of order (it was the same on my machine) and you get two distinct arrays which will get collected into two rows in the following `groupby`.

To solve the "problem" you should explicitly state that you would like the arrays to be sorted (use `array_sort` after you `collect_list`).

```
.agg(f.array_sort(f.collect_list(f.col(f"id{index[0]}"))).alias(f"id{index[0]}_tmp"))
```

or collect values to a set with `collect_set` as sets do not have order:

```
.agg(f.collect_set(f.col(f"id{index[0]}")).alias(f"id{index[0]}_tmp"))
```

Problem was not easy to find because you've got a lot of generic code with looping, renaming etc.

I hope that helps.